# What technologies do facebook games generally use?

Tags: mysql, facebook, flash, adobe

I'm interested in beginning to write facebook games.  A quick google search for technologies of facebook games didn't give me a whole lot.  It seems like Flash is quite popular.

What other technologies do companies/individuals generally use to write their games?

I am experienced in the industry w/ Java, Adobe Flex (never used Flash though), PHP, MySql, Javascript, XML, etc.

I am wondering where the best place to start is and also if anyone has recommendations on good books to get started with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About 99% of Facebook games , use Adobe Flash to develop the games. 
Since flash has actionscript support its very easy to control objects what you define inside.

Some links to get you started for game development in flash.

[www.emanueleferonato.com/.../flash-game-creation-tutorial-part-1/](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/10/29/flash-game-creation-tutorial-part-1/)

[www.good-tutorials.com/tutorials/flash/game-development](http://www.good-tutorials.com/tutorials/flash/game-development)

[www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/Flash/Games/1](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/Flash/Games/1)

Comment: Thanks..Do most of these apps connect to php on the back end then?  (Or is it just whatever you want?)

Answer (score 3):

You wrote:

> if anyone has recommendations on good books to get started with.

If you have no game development experience in Flash at all, start with:

> **Foundation Game Design with Flash** by Rex van der Spuy,

Two excellent books for intermediate level Flash Game Programming are:

> **AdvancED Game Design with Flash** by Rex van der Spuy

and

> **The Essential Guide to Flash Games: Building Interactive Entertainment 
>       with ActionScript** by Jeff Fulton and Steve Fulton

These books have complete games as tutorial examples.